# Reset Password Email

Tags: php, laravel, email, frameworks, laravel-blade

I am new to laravel development and currently working on small project. I would like to customize the email template for the reset passwords or even link it to completely different template. For the authentication scaffolding I have used the **php artisan make:auth** command.

However the default reset password functionality uses default laravel email template. Is it possible that I can create different email template and link it to reset password Controller? Also I would like to pass in additional user information in.

I am using laravel 5.4 version.

Comment: In the bottom of the page: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passwords#resetting-views

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a Notification class with:

```
php artisan make:notification ResetPassword
```

You can override `toMail()` method there to customize subject and line.

```
   public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Reset Password Request')
            ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
            ->action('Reset Password', url('password/reset', $this->token))
            ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
    }
```

And in `users` model:

```
   use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
   use App\Notifications\ResetPassword as ResetPasswordNotification;

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
        {
            $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
        }
```

And to customize whole email template. here is the view: `resources/views/notification/email.blade.php;`

And in `config/app.php`, You can change the application name, default is laravel.