# where is the blade file of the reset password?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

in laravel 5.6

I used the following command to generate auth files:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

but I can not find the blade.php file used for reset password email to edit it.

where is it?

Comment: [Again, Laravel will generate all of the necessary views for password reset when the make:auth command is executed. These views are placed in resources/views/auth/passwords. You are free to customize them as needed for your application.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passwords#resetting-views). Please search for your question before posting an answer as a duplicate is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217818/reset-password-email?rq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset Password Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217818/reset-password-email)

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in the following folder:

> resources\views\auth\passwords

Answer (score 1):

The default directory is

> resources\views\auth\passwords

If not, you should do a clean installation.